# How to represent (enum) types in a public API

Tags: api, patterns-and-practices, enum

I am working on a simple API that I want to use for my own client, and to open to the public in the future.
I have "Item" objects which can have different "types". The type is a C "typedef enum", for the moment I have :

```
typedef enum {
    ItemTypeBool,
    ItemTypeNumber,
    ItemTypeDate,
} ItemType;
```

(I may add some in the future)

I am wondering if I should rather transfer it as integers or as defined "strings". The JSON would be :

For integers :

```
{
  "name": "The name",
  "type": 0,
   ...
}
```

For strings :

```
{
  "name": "The name"
  "type": "boolean"
   ...
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a best practice for this. Keeping the integer would slightly simplify the code, and reduce the bandwidth, but strings would be easier for developers to remember. I remember I worked on a project, and I had to remember 1=image, 2=audio, 3=html,... which doesn't make any real sense.

So I'm asking you, if you know any other aspect I should consider.

Comment: Do you expect your users to edit the JSON manually often?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Provide the strings. Numbers are meaningless. You don't use them in your own code, right (you're wrapping enum values around, that are basically strings) - why punish the user with having to use these numbers?

The only pro if you do expose the numbers - easier for you to parse these. But hey, who cares about you. Take care of the API clients.

If you provide the strings - easier for the clients; won't ever have to say things like "4 had been deprecated in favor of 17"; slightly harder parsing on your behalf, but that's fine.

Do not provide both: as a user, i'm left to wonder

- which one do I use? Both? *[on to reading docs]*
- why are there two ways to say the same thing? are they subtly different? *[on to reading docs]*
- what if I specify both and there's a mismatch? will it complain? will one take precedence? which one? *[on to reading docs]*

As you can see, you're having me read a lot of docs for no reason.

Comment: I agree with @iluxa

Comment: What if enum is member of the class(object) expected as input in rest call?

Answer (score 3):

Strings.

One of Json's strengths is that its human-readable. When debugging the output half a year from now "0" will tell you nothing.

Some frameworks will do auto-conversion too. If you're not using one - you can create a converter yourself to keep your code dry.

This turns in a vote casting, though.

Answer (score 1):

Best Practice depends on who is consuming your API.  If you are trying to make life easy for the consumer, you should provide sample code in C, JAVA, iOS, python, ruby that can consume your api.  In these wrappers you can include the enum, use an int in json, and then just parse your json into an object with the enum already set, and return this object to the users code.

Another thing you could do is provide both. for instance:

```
{
  "name": "The name",
  "typeId": 0,
  "type": "ItemTypeBool"
   ...
}
```

Or you can use type, and typeStr depending on what looks best for your api.

And then clearly state in your documentation that these are redundant and it's up to the developer to choose which is best for their application.

Look at the json here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search
Twitter has an example of providing redundant data (id and id_str) , but this because some json clients cant parse long ints from a "number" in json and require a string to avoid losing digits